# Find the max average for each country - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, average

For each country, report the book with the highest average rating. If two or more books have the same average rating, report the one with the highest number of ratings. If two or more books are still tie (same highest average rating and same number of ratings), report them all sorted alphabetically on book title. If a country is not associated to any ratings, it should not show up in the query output.
[myTablesSample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA1Rq.png)

```
    SELECT  CountryName, Title, AVG(CAST(Rate AS DECIMAL)) as AverageRatePerCountry, count(Rate) as NumberOfRates
    FROM bda.booksRatings as BR2
    left JOIN bda.books as B2 on B2.ISBN = BR2.ISBN
    left JOIN bda.users as U2 ON U2.UserID = BR2.UserID
    left JOIN bda.countries as C2 on U2.CountryCode = C2.CountryCode


    GROUP BY CountryName, Title 

    ORDER BY CountryName desc, AverageRatePerCountry desc, NumberOfRates desc, Title asc
```

I tried adding the below but clearly it does not work,

```
     having AVG(CAST(Rate AS DECIMAL)) >=all and count(Rate) >= all
```

This is Homework, am not 100% sure if it is allowed to ask.
But, please i do not want the solution, just some pointers on what i am losing here.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please do NOT post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This sounds a LOT like homework.

Comment: I expect that your solution will need to utilize either nested subqueries or Common Table Expressions (CTEs) to build up your answer in steps. You should also take a look at the RANK function.

Comment: I would go with CTE, as @TN hinted.  Would look something like:  WITH countsTable AS (SELECT SUM(...), COUNT(...), etc FROM primaryTable) SELECT ... FROM countsTable WHERE ...

Comment: You could wrap the `AVG` in a [DENSE_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql) with descending order, then select where the rank equals 1 from the sub-query.

Comment: We have not used RANKS in lectures, so he does not expect a solution with ranks..